# D3: Keep mouseover Open While Mouse is Over Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm using [d3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/) for tooltips on my graph. And am trying to work out if there's an easy way to keep the tooltips open for a brief period of time?

Once I `mouseout` on the node, it fires the `.hide()` method, I can never actually hover over the tooltip.

I think I need a way to `mouseover` the tooltip element so I can fire the `.show()` method, like so:

```
tip.on('mouseover', function(d) {
  tip.show(d);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do this...

I've set up a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hx8pjwdu/1/).

Any ideas if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could overwrite the hide method with a setTimeout ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: But this would just delay it from closing by X seconds. I want it so when you hover over the tooltip the tooltip displays indefinitely until you hover off the tooltip.

Comment: Ahh, well your fiddle is doing that now..

Comment: I have updated your fiddle... kindly check http://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/hx8pjwdu/2/ donno exactly thats what you are looking for

Comment: @RRR I'd prefer not use any `setTimeout` hacks. I still want the tooltip to disappear when you hover off it, I just want it to keep the tooltip visible when you're hovering over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/hx8pjwdu/9/

```
     .on('mouseover', function(d) {     
       d3.select(".d3-tip").transition().style("opacity", "1");
       tip.show(d);
     })
     .on('mouseout', function(d) {
       d3.select(".d3-tip").transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", "0").each("end", tip.hide);
     });
  d3.select(".d3-tip").on('mouseover', function(d) {
       d3.select(".d3-tip").transition().style("opacity", "1");
     }).on('mouseout', function(d) {
       d3.select(".d3-tip").transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", "0").each("end", tip.hide);
     });
```

I added a mouseover event for your d3-tip and made its hide event a fadeout.

Comment: When I use more data points, the tooltip appearing/disappearing is very inconsistent. http://jsfiddle.net/hx8pjwdu/6/. Try hovering over multiple tooltips one after another.

Comment: When the tooltip disappears, if you hover over the space where the tooltip was, it reappears. Any way to stop this from happening and only have the tooltips appear when you hover over the nodes?

Comment: @realph Sure, just add a callback on the end function to hide it completely. http://jsfiddle.net/hx8pjwdu/9/

Comment: How does this work? Surely hovering over the space reignites the tooltip...?

Comment: @realph what do you mean? with the last fiddle it shouldn't appear when you you hover over where the tooltip was after it has dissappeared

Comment: Ahh the problem I was having seems to have stemmed from the `pointer-events` I had set to `auto`. This was making the tooltips reappear. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/hx8pjwdu/10/

Comment: @realph Ah glad you fount that out